# Is it possible to catch a exception of unjoined thread termination in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception

I have a thread running in an endless loop to do some work. Now I want to terminate the program smoothly without any error, is it possible to just terminate the thread without join and just catch the exception?

I tried the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void foo()
{
    // simulate expensive operation
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
}
 
void bar()
{
    // simulate expensive operation
    while (true)
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
}
 
int main()
{
    cout << "starting first helper...\n";
    thread helper1(foo);
 
    cout << "starting second helper...\n";
    shared_ptr<thread> helper2 = make_shared<thread>(bar);
 
    cout << "waiting for helpers to finish..." << endl;
    helper1.join();

    try {
        helper2.reset(); // drop thread without join
    } catch (exception e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
 
    cout << "done!\n";
}
```

And I got following result:

```
starting first helper...
starting second helper...
waiting for helpers to finish...
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Looks like there's no exception thrown. Why?

Comment: [`~thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) calls `std::terminate` if the thread is joinable. It does not throw an exception. It is a logic error to destroy a joinable thread.

Answer (score 2):

No you can not because it is not an exception, the threads destructor calls std::terminate direct.

A way around this depends on what you want.
If you use jthread instead of thread, the destructor will call join itself.
If you do not need access to the thread anymore, you can detach the thread before destructing it.

Comment: `detach` will solve the immediate destruction problem, but it is almost always an error to use it. The process won't wait for the thread to finish and it may be interrupted at any time. Presumably, if you start a thread, you want it to do something but you cannot rely on a detached thread for anything unless you implement your own synchronization, in which case you might as well `join` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `while (true)` you can pass in an atomic bool, which the main thread changes when it wants to exit, and joins the thread:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>

void expensive_func() {
  std::puts("Start expensive_func");
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  std::puts("End expensive_func");
}

void daemon(std::atomic<bool> const* running) {
  while (*running) {
    expensive_func();
  }
}

int main() {
  std::atomic<bool> running = true;

  std::thread worker(daemon, &running);

  // Do something
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

  // Done, let the thread know that we're done
  running = false;

  // Join the worker
  worker.join();
}
```

You can also wrap this whole thing in a `DaemonThread` class, so the cleanup happens automatically and it's exception-safe.